# Validate the input I'm focus on, no matter what is the status of the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm having this issue I need to solve... What I want to do is to validate exactly the input user is filling in the moment, no matter if the first one or any other input are empty, and the other is not send the ajax post request if every single input has been validated.

This is the code i have so far:

```
function sendInfo() {

    //variables
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var surname = $("input#surname").val();

    //inputs validation
    if (name == "") {
        $("input#name").focus();
        $("input#name").parent().find('span').addClass('err').text('you have to fill the name');
        return false;
    } 
     if (surname == "") {
        $("input#surname").focus();
        $("input#surname").parent().find('span').addClass('err').text("you have to fill the surname");
        return false;
    } 

        //Manage server side

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/path',
            data: {name, surname},
            success: function (result) {
                //all ok, do something
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //something wrong, do other stuff
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: if you want all validation to execute each time remove the `returns` in each validation and set a single variable to false instead, then check the variable before making the ajax call and skip the call if it is false? `var isValid = true;` before the validation, then `isValid = false` instead of `return false`. Check `if(!isValid){return;}` before the ajax call. Further you should prop wrap your validation into a single function to call from anywhere. That way you can do `if(!validateForm()){return;}`  before the ajax and `return isValid;` inside `validateForm`

Comment: if the user is already filling what you need to validate?

Comment: Also, If you always want to validate all setting focus makes little sense as you always end up on the last invalid field ignoring the others. I would not set the focus at all and if you must set it, set it to the first invalid field not the last, might be more user friendly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
function sendInfo() {
    //variables
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var surname = $("input#surname").val();
    var error = false;

    //inputs validation
    if (name == "") {
        $("input#name").focus();
        $("input#name").parent().find('span').addClass('err').text('you have to fill the name');
        error = true;
    } 
     if (surname == "") {
        $("input#surname").focus();
        $("input#surname").parent().find('span').addClass('err').text("you have to fill the surname");
        error = true;
    } 

    if (error) return false;

        //Manage server side

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/path',
            data: {name, surname},
            success: function (result) {
                //all ok, do something
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //something wrong, do other stuff
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a bool variable isValid. Your code should be like this

```
function sendInfo() {
//variables
var isValid = true;
var name = $("input#name").val();
var surname = $("input#surname").val();

//inputs validation
if (name == "") {
    $("input#name").focus();
    $("input#name").parent().find('span').addClass('err').text('you have to fill the name');
    isValid = false;
} 
 if (surname == "") {
    $("input#surname").focus();
    $("input#surname").parent().find('span').addClass('err').text("you have to fill the surname");
    isValid = false;
} 

    //Manage server side
if(isValid){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path',
        data: {name, surname},
        success: function (result) {
            //all ok, do something
        },
        error: function (err) {
            //something wrong, do other stuff
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(isValid)` is plenty, it's a boolean :) Anyway, don't do `if(isValid === true){ //lots of code here}` but instead do `if(!isValid){return}` way easier to maintain and read. - Always try to avoid nesting when ever possible. It results in cleaner, more readable code.

Comment: ok thanks let me edit my code and we have to check true so will use if(isValid)

Comment: While it's fine in your answer, in general you don't **have** to check `isValid`, checking `!isValid` allows you to break out without adding unnecessary nesting and is a good habit to get into for writing clean code, which make code easier to manage and refactor when needed.

Answer (score -1):

Try to validate the inputs onfocus() AND before the post.

```
    var checkInput = function(input) {
       if (input.val() == '') {
        input.parent().find('span').addClass('err').text('you have to fill the name');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }

    function sendInfo() {
        var validForm = false;
        $('input').each(function(){
           validForm = checkInput($(this));
        });
        if (validForm) {
           alert('ok - do the post');
        } else {
          alert('fill the fields');
        }
}

    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('input').on('focus',function() {
          checkInput($(this));
      });
  });
```

Comment: If you go down the route of generic global input validation make sure you don't call all the fields `name` in your error message!

Answer (score -1):

Add a certain class to every field you want validated. Then bind an event on the elements with that class that will validate the fields upon change. If it's validated correctly store this info on the element.

For example you'd have your fields like this

```
<input type='text' id='some-text-1' class='validated-field'>
<input type='text' id='some-text-2' class='validated-field'>
<input type='text' id='some-text-3' class='validated-field'>
```

Then a script which binds the events

```
$('.validated-field').on('input', function(){
    validate($(this));
});
```

*Note: This will "fire" basically after each keypress, not only after you finish editing.*

*Note2: Depending on how you create the elements, if you want to call this after `document.ready` then you'll have to bind this to an element which is indeed ready at the time.*

Your validate function should perform the necessary validations and then mark the element with in a certain way, for example

```
function validate($element){
    var value = $element.val();
    // var isValid = your validation here
    $element.data("valid", isValid);
}
```

This will produce elements for example like these

```
<input type='text' id='some-text-1' class='validated-field' data-valid=true>
<input type='text' id='some-text-2' class='validated-field' data-valid=false>
<input type='text' id='some-text-3' class='validated-field'>
```

The first one validated correctly, the second one is incorrect and the third isn't validated yet, because user hasn't filled it out yet.

With this you can check if every one of these elements is validated

```
validateElements(className){
    var elements = $('.' + className);
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        if(!$(elements[i]).data("valid") === true){
            return false; //at least one isn't validated OK
        }
    }
    return true; //all good
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. If you have any other questions, feel free to comment.

Comment: It's usually accustomed to comment, when you downvote someone. Were all learning here and your blind downvotes aren't really welcome here, especially considering it was downvoted about 5 seconds after posing. You're either a super fast reader, or you're trying to boost your answer which makes you even more unwelcome.